# How arrange data from an arraylist in two divs using struts2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a set of images in an ArayList. I am trying to arrange these images in rows, with each row containing 4 images. So if there are 10 images in the arraylist, there should be 3 rows with 4 in first, 4 in second and 2 in third row.

Here is my jsp.

```
<s:iterator value="productList" status="status">
    <div class="display">   
        <div class="block">
            <img src="../product/image?imageID=<s:property value="productID"/>&type=thumbnail" />
        </div>
    </div>
</s:iterator>
```

Here div with class display acts as the rows.
div with the class block acts as the columns inside the display div.

How can it be done? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approachs that i can think of..
1. Table(easiest)
2. ul li

In the table approach the code will look something like

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="productList" status="status">
        <s:if test="#status.index %4 == 0">
            <tr>
        </s:if>

                <td>
                    <img src="../product/image?imageID=<s:property value="productID"/>&type=thumbnail" />
                </td>
         <s:if test="#status.index %4 == 0">
            </tr>
         </s:if>
</s:iterator>
<table>
```

Also you might want to check after the iterator if the  tag has to be closed

Comment: we dont use tables in our project. We use div only, can this be done with divs?

Comment: ok. same logic... instead of <tr> use <div class="display>" & instead of <td> use <div style="float: left">... or if you dont want to use float, look at the style "display : inline-block"

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Only a minor change #status.index to #status.count as #status.index starts from 0.