# Showing products in grid

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page where I am showing all the products that fall under a specific category. The problem is that all of them either end up showing either vertically or horizontally based on whether I loop my "td" or "tr". I want to show them in grid where 3 products are in row 1, another 3 in row 2 and so on. Any idea on how this can be achieved?

**ProductController.java**

```
List<Product> productsLst = MasterDao.getAllProductsByCategory(new Integer(categoryId));
```

**products.jsp**

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <%
        for (Product p : productsLst) {
    %>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="product.jsp?productId=<%= p.getProductId() %>"><img src="../images/<%= p.getImage()%>" class="product-grid-img"/></a>
        <br/><div id="product-name"><%= p.getName()%></div>
        <br/><div id="money">$&nbsp;<%= p.getListPrice()%></div>
    </td>
    <%
        }
    %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. It's not so difficult: every three product, you must close the tr and open a new one. Or you could build a `List<List<Product>>` and use two nested loops. See Guava's `Lists.partition()` method: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a counter, if you got 3 products close the tr and open a new tr

Answer (score 0):

Using Guava's [Lists.partition()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29) method:

```
List<List<Product>> rows = Lists.partition(productList);
page.setAttribute("rows", rows);
...
<c:forEach var="row" items="rows">
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="product" items="row">
            <td> ... details of the product ... </td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387285/how-arrange-data-from-an-arraylist-in-two-divs-using-struts2/12387534#12387534)

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="productList" status="status">
        <s:if test="#status.index %4 == 0">
            <tr>
        </s:if>

                <td>
                    <img src="../product/image?imageID=<s:property value="productID"/>&type=thumbnail" />
                </td>
         <s:if test="#status.index %4 == 0">
            </tr>
         </s:if>
</s:iterator>
<table>
```